# How to serve a downloadable docx file created with OpenXML SDK in .Net Core

Tags: download, asp.net-core-mvc, openxml-sdk

In my .net core 2.2 MVC web app, I am currently generating a .docx file using OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool.

Currently, when the user fills in the form on my View and hits Submit, the OpenXML code is triggered and the *word doc is generated, and emailed to a user*. What I now need is the word document file to be also available to download for that user.

I'm not sure how to re-work my code to get this to work. Below is my `[HTTPPost]` method:

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult AddReferralForm(ReferralForm referralForm)

{

try

{

//generate word document of the referral form

var GeneratedClassOpenXML = new OpenXMLGeneratedClass();

var wwwRoot = _env.WebRootPath;

string constructedFilename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_"+ DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmm") + "_";

string fileName = referralFormsLocation + constructedFilename+".docx";

 
var emailaddressToSendForm = _context.ReferralFormEmailAddresses.FirstOrDefault();

//Generate Word Document referral form - uses Open XML SDK

GeneratedClassOpenXML.CreatePackage(fileName, referralForm, LoggedInUser, emailaddressToSendForm.EmailAddress);

//method for user to download the word doc
ExportReferral(fileName);



return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = LoggedInUser.Id });

}

catch (Exception ex)

{

throw new Exception("Error when saving a referral - " + ex);

}

}
```

This method redirects the user back to `Home/Index`. The emailing of the generated word document is within `GeneratedClassOpenXML.CreatePackage()`.

I thought something like this code could work, with my HTTPPost method above calling this, but this didn't work:

```
[HttpGet]       
public IActionResult ExportReferral(string filePath)
{
    var x = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath),
    contentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    fileDownloadName: "MySheet.docx");

}
```

I am trying  to look for a way to return the user to the home page and return the file content. Any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: How will you display file content? Download directly or showing in view.  You can only return one response (redirect or download) to a HTTP request.

Comment: I was hoping for a download prompt to appear, or whatever the simplest way is really.

How else could I achieve this perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to Home with path

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddReferralForm(ReferralForm referralForm)

{

   //Generate Word Document referral form - uses Open XML SDK
   ...
   redirect home/index with fileName 
   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { id = LoggedInUser.Id, file= fileName });

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<!-- you can have your own style -->
<style>
    /* dialog div must be hidden */
    #basicModal {
        display: none;
    }
</style>


<div id="basicModal">
    Confirm to download ?
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const downloadUrl = urlParams.get('file');

        //window.location = downloadUrl;
        if (downloadUrl != null) {
            $("#basicModal").dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: "Are you sure?",
                buttons: {
                    "YES": function () {
                        window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank');
                    },
                    "NO": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Just a question - would I have to retrieve the actual file (word doc) from the server in my Home/Index method?

Comment: Yes, and also `AddReferralForm`  could redirect `home/index` with file path.